# function called after first function is being ran first in swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating a friends list on my app, fetchfriends makes a list of users that person is friends with, fetch user then looks at this list and populates a table view with friends information. This seems like it would work fine but for some reason fetch user is being ran before fetch friends can anyone help me with this? This is my code. I even tried a conditional statement which is now commented out and it just never ran the second function that way.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()


    friendsTableView.delegate = self
    friendsTableView.dataSource = self

    fetchfriends()

    //if userspresent == true {
    fetchuser()
   // }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}



    func fetchfriends () {

    ref.child("users").child(userID!).child("friends").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {

            let userName = value["username"] as? String ?? ""
            let friendid = value["userid"] as? String ?? ""

            self.userIds.append(friendid)
            self.userspresent = true
        print(userName, friendid)
        }
    })
}

   // var index1:Int = 0
    //if userspresent == true {
func fetchuser () {

    //let count = userIds.count
    for index1 in 0...userIds.count-1 {
        ref.child("users").child(userIds[index1]).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let user = User()
        let userName = value?["username"] as? String ?? ""
        let email = value?["email"] as? String ?? ""
        let profileImageUrl = value?["profileImage"] as? String ?? ""
        user.userName = userName
        user.email = email
        user.profileImageUrl = profileImageUrl
        print(user)
        self.users.append(user)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.friendsTableView.reloadData()
        }



        print(user.userName!, user.email!)

       // print(snapshot)
    }, withCancel: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code suggest that you perform asynchronous actions. It will then end fetchfriends() immediately and take actions in the background. You should consider moving fetchuser() into the action that happens in fetchfriends(), just after that print.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Taylor M is correct.  These are asynchronous network operations, so you can't really say for certain which one will be completed first.  However, since `fetchuser` relies on data produced in `fetchfriends` (namely, that there will be values in `userIds`) you can simply add a closure as a parameter to `fetchfriends`:

```
func fetchfriends (_ completion: ((Void) -> Void)?) {
    ref.child("users").child(userID!).child("friends").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    if let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {

        let userName = value["username"] as? String ?? ""
        let friendid = value["userid"] as? String ?? ""

        self.userIds.append(friendid)
        self.userspresent = true
        print(userName, friendid)

        // call the closure function upon completion
        completion?()
    }
})
```

Now, when you call `fetchfriends` in `viewDidLoad` simply do:

```
fetchfriends {
    // this will be called when the friends are successfully fetched
    self.fetchuser()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is asyncronous network calls. You're incorrect in saying that fetch user is being ran before fetch friends if your code is as follows:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...
    fetchfriends()

    //if userspresent == true {
    fetchuser()
    // }
}
```

In your `observeSingleEvent` call you provide this function a closure to run *after* firebase observes that event.

So you call `fetchfriends` (first) which calls an `observeSingleEvent`. The OS places this network call on a background thread to do its work, and when the network call is finished, your provided closure is executed. Meanwhile, on the main thread, your program keeps running and calls `fetchuser` (second) which also calls `observeSingeEvent` and places that call and closure on a different background thread and your program keeps running. Most likely it seems as though the closure written in the `fetchuser` method is be run first because that network takes less time and is the first one back.

Comment: okay thank you, but how can I make sure that fetch user isnt ran until fetchfriends is finished?

Comment: Simply, make the `fetchuser` call in the closure of the `fetchfriends`'s `observeSingleEvent` call.

Comment: With more flexibility, add a [closure](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html) to the `fetchfriends` method and have the call to `fetchuser` be in that closure that you'll call after the code to parse the friends data.